# Motivation of $C_0$ in a proof of Hahn-Banach Theorem in Reverse Maths

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-explanation, reverse-math

Currently I am reading [Simpson's Subsystem of Second Order Arithmetic](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/subsystems-of-second-order-arithmetic/EA16CB4305831530B7015D6BC46B7424).

---

Definition $4.9.2$ The following definitions are made in $RCA_0$:
Given a separable Banach space $\hat{A},$ a **subspace** of $\hat{A}$ consists of a separable Banach space $\hat{S}$ together with a bounded linear operator $\psi:\hat{S}\to\hat{A}$ such that 
$$\psi(x)\| = \|x\| \quad \text{for all }x\in \hat{S}.$$
We identify $x\in\hat{S}$ with $\psi(x)\in\hat{A}.$
If $\hat{B}$ is another separable Banach space and $F:\hat{S}\to \hat{B}$ is a bounded linear operator,  we  say that $\tilde{F}:\hat{A}\to\hat{B}$ extends $F$ if 
$$\tilde{F}(\psi(x)) = F(x) \quad \text{for all }x\in \hat{S}.$$

---

At Chapter 4 Weak Konig Lemma, section $4.9$ the separable Hahn/Banach Theorem, the author provided a proof for Hahn/Banach Theorem.

> **Theorem $4.9.13$** The following is provable in $WKL_0.$
>   Let $\hat{A}$ be a separable Banach space and let $\hat{S}$ be a subspace of $\hat{A}.$
>   Let $f:\hat{S}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded linear functional such that $\|f\|\leq \alpha,$ where $\alpha$ is a positive real number.
>   Then there exists a bounded linear functional $\tilde{f}:\hat{A}\to\mathbb{R}$ extending $f$ such that $\|\tilde{f}\|\leq\alpha.$

The following is a proof.

> Proof: We may safely assume that $\alpha = 1.$
>   Let 
>   $$A = \{a_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}\quad\text{and}\quad S=\{s_i:\mathbb{N}\}.$$
>   We may safely assume that $a_0=s_0=0.$
>   Let $C_0$ be the closed convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ consisting of those sequences $\langle z_i:i\in\mathbb{N} \rangle$ such that $z_0=0$ and 
>   $$|z_i-z_j|\leq \|a_i-a_j\|$$
>   for all $I,j\in\mathbb{N}.$
>   $C_0$ is included in the compact product space 
>   $$\prod_{I\in\mathbb{N}}[-\|a_i\|,\|a_i\|].$$
>   To each $z = \langle z_i:\in\mathbb{N} \rangle \in C_0$ is associated a continuous function 
>   $$g=g_z:\hat{A}\to\mathbb{R}$$
>   such that $g(a_i)=z_i$ for all $I\in\mathbb{N}.$

In the remaining of the proof, the authors defined the following four sets in sequence.

$$C_0= \{ (z_i:i\in\mathbb{N})\in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}: z_0=0, |z_i-z_j|\leq \|a_i-a_j\|, \text{ for all }i,j\in\mathbb{N} \},$$
$$C_1 = \{g\in C_0: g(\psi(s)) = f(s) \text{ for all }s\in \hat{S}\},$$
$$C_2 = \{ g\in C_1: g(x+\psi(s)) = g(x) + g(\psi(s) \text{ for all }x\in \hat{A} \text{ and }s\in \hat{S}) \},$$
$$C_3 = \{g\in C_2: g(x+y) = g(x)+g(y)\}.$$

> **Question**: What is a motivation of defining $C_0?$

I have pondered about it for a few days but not able to solve it.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without more context (or the exact book on the desk)

Comment: @daw added a portion of the proof. Is it okay now?

Comment: The question here is not very clear: in the simplest sense the motivation for defining $C_0$  is to prove the Hahn-Banach theorem.  In any case, it may help to look at another exposition, such as pp 28ff of the linked pdf: Shioji and Tanaka, "[Fixed point theory in weak second-order arithmetic](https://repository.kulib.kyoto-u.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2433/100734/1/0669-03.pdf)", Annals of Pure and Applied Logic 47, 1990.   Simpson refers to this reference in the notes for section IV.9.

Comment: @CarlMummert I would like to know an intuition behind defining $C_0.$ Because if I were to prove the theorem myself, I would not be able to think of $C_0.$ In fact, a proof of HBT that I know is through extending domains. However, Simpson seems to 'shrink' instead of 'extending'.

Comment: I think that Shoiji and Tanaka explain at the top of page 29. Most likely, the problem with the "extending domains" method is that it requires $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ to formalize, while the actual result is equivalent to $\mathsf{WKL}_0$. In situations like that, we need an alternate proof.

Comment: @CarlMummert I see. However, I actually came across another proof of HBT, which deals with shrinking on the collection of sublinear functionals. Then they claim that the minimum elements is linear. The proof can be found at chapter 3 of the book https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4939-1945-1

Comment: @CarlMummert Brown and Simpson prove Hahn-Banach theorem in $WKL_0$ using standard extension in functional analysis. Its proof can be found here, in particular theorem $6.4$ https://ac.els-cdn.com/0168007286900667/1-s2.0-0168007286900667-main.pdf?_tid=f723c73e-394e-4004-baa9-8a1943823d97&acdnat=1541510302_cbd5c21f78f4ac45d79f6312f8ac1972

Comment: @Idonknow: thanks for the reference!  Would you say that Lemma 6.3 is the standard extension method? I see Theorem 5.6, which I think is a more standard proof in which the functional is extended, using induction, to larger and larger subspaces. That theorem uses $\mathsf{ACA}^+_0$, however, more than just $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ that I had speculated.